# наследование - прототипы

Tags: javascript

```
function IO() {
    this.foo = function() {
        alert("FOO");
    }
}
IO.prototype.bar = function() {
  alert("BAR");
}
var IO = new IO();
console.log(IO);
```

[image: console.log]

Какая разница между объявлениями через `this` и `prototype`?

Comment: добавление в текущий объект - соответственно у каждого экземпляра будет своя копия поля/функции, либо добавление в прототип и все объекты будут иметь доступ к одному экзепляру поля/функции

Comment: не совсем правда понял при чем тут наследование

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В этом случае функция будет создаваться каждый раз при создании объекта, и может использовать в замыкании переменные объявленные внутри конструктора

```
function IO() {
  var _private = 10;
  this.foo = function() {
    _private = 15;//OK
    alert("FOO");
  }
}
```

В этом случае функции создается один раз и не имеет доступа к переменным локально объявленным в конструкторе

```
IO.prototype.bar = function() {
  var some = _private + 15;// Uncaught ReferenceError: _private is not defined
  alert("BAR");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Как Grundy сказал в комментариях, это

```
this.foo = function() { /*...*/ }
```

создаёт копию функции для каждого экземпляра, а это

```
IO.prototype.bar = function() { /*...*/ }
```

создаёт одну функцию для всех экземпляров. Можно видеть эту разницу таким образом:

```
var a = new IO(),
    b = new IO();
console.log(a.foo === b.foo); // false
console.log(a.bar === b.bar); // true
```

Comment: :-D я потом еще и ответ успел накатать

Comment: @Grundy Я заметил, еще и голосовал)

Comment: кстати, спасибо за правку, я точно не помнил как именно может выглядеть ошибка когда к необъявленной переменной обращаемся